# Android Listview row's ImageView OnClick delay

Tags: android, listview, optimization, onclick, imageview

Similar to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0M3IDRhw8Kw), I'm having a delay in the click response of a view inside the ListView's row.

Also, the click listener is immediately fired when a view outside the listview gained focus.

My question is, is there any other way to solve this, apart from ditching ListView altogether, as suggested on the link above?

Answer (score 0):

I had come with the same issue and I just solved it with help of others.

It seems you used a hash array to save Listview rows in order to avoid inflate new view multiple times while implementing **getView()** method.

However using hash array will make the listener's status mess so it will cause the problem you described.

So delete the hash array and just only return row view in getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. I hope I can help you.
I solved it by using OnTouchListener, each row, I set a OnTouchListener, like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        lastTimeTouch = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    else
    if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        long c = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (c- lastTimeTouch< 2000)
            onClick(view);//call your onClick() funtion here
        lastTimeTouch = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```